# Get single edit field from a content type

Tags: forms

I'm writing a module with a custom form. I would to add in this a form a field from an existent content type, with values.

For example: I've a content type "article" wth a node reference field "field_ref".

In my custom form I want to get this "field_ref" field, with values.
Is it possible?

I think that I could get the entire form and then get only the field but I don't like this solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can build a custom autocomplete text field to filter node reference results. Check this link http://timonweb.com/how-create-ajax-autocomplete-textfield-drupal-7 to build autocomplete text field.

You just need to change the query in above implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your field is a list type, you can grab the allowed values from the field using the [`field_info_field()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7) function:

```
$info = field_info_field('field_states');
$options = $info['settings']['allowed_values'];

$form['work_state'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Work State'),
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => $options
);
```

I got hint from this link of [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841842/retrieving-a-list-from-content-type-field-in-drupal-7/10842515#10842515)

Check this link again from stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225158/drupal-7-programmatic-field-definition

This allows you to create node reference field

Comment: This is ok, but I need to create a node_reference field, populated  from values of a node (that I get with a view). I'm now searching api to create node_reference field

Comment: check my edit of answer

Comment: getting a list is ok, also add values from a view or a query. But I need to create in the form a node_reference field